# How can I hide my UIImageView after the animation is completed?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, segue, uianimation

How can I hide my `UIImageView` after the animation is completed? My animation is working fine when I segue into the view. I want to be a able to hide the image after the animation is complete. How might I do that?

```
-(void) animate
{
    NSLog(@"Animate");

    CGPoint startPoint = [pickerCircle center];
    CGPoint endPoint = [pickerButton1 center];

    CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath, NULL, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(thePath, NULL, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    animation.duration = 3.f;
    animation.path = thePath;
    animation.repeatCount = 2;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    [pickerCircle.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
    pickerCircle.layer.position = endPoint;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the animation's delegate property to self like so:

```
animation.delegate = self;
```

And then you can use:

```
-(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
    // hide your UIImage here
}
```

It will be called when the animation is done.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try completion? [Here example 4.2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html)there is an example about showing and hiding an view with using completion. 
I don't know animations well but I think completion should work.

Comment: Sorry, this does not really answer my question. Yes I see examples in other types of animations that use `completion`: blocks, I am looking specifically for help with the `CAKeyframeAnimation`